# ng-repeat не обновляет данные из массива

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Есть приложение на angular1.6. Необходимо передавать на страницу данные которые вводит пользователь и сохранять их. Для реализации был выбран метод перебора массива из локал сторэдж. Массив копируется из массива сервиса. Но почему-то при добавлении данных в массив, в браузере динамически ничего не меняется. 
Шаблон:

```
<div ng-controller="laDashboardController">
    <ul ng-repeat="site in arrData.items track by $index">
        <li class="ul" >
            <p><b>Site name: {{site.siteNames}}</b></p>
            <p>Site name: {{site.siteUrls}}</p>
            <p>Site password: {{site.sitePasses}}</p>
            <input ng-model="newName" placeholder="Enter site name to change it"></input>
            <input ng-model="newPass" placeholder="Enter password to change it"></input>
            <button ng-click="$ctrl.change(newName, newPass, site.siteNames)">Change it</button>
            <button ng-click="$ctrl.deleteItem(site.siteNames)">Delete</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Код контроллера

```
setData(siteName, siteUrl, sitePass) {
  console.log(this.$scope.arrData)
  const finalObject = {
        siteNames: siteName,
        siteUrls: siteUrl,
        sitePasses: sitePass
  };
  //console.log(finalObject)
  //this.arrData = this.dataService.setData
  this.dataService.setStorage(finalObject);
  this.$scope.arrData = this.dataService.setData;      


}
```

И код сервиса

```
   this.setStorage = function setStorage(data) {
  console.log(data)
  this.setData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.name));
  this.setData['items'].push(data);
  this.setLocal()

}
```

Все работает, массив постоянно обновляться, но данных нет, пока не обновишь страницу

Comment: замени строку `this.setData['items'].push(data)` на `this.setData['items'] = this.setData['items'].concat(data)`;

Comment: Массив обновляет. Даже работают остальные методы, типа удалить или изменить, но не выводит динамически новые данные. И я обновил то что вы прислали, изменений нет

Comment: Да, логично, это все надо потом еще раз в `$scope.arrData` присвоить

Comment: @Grundy не понимаю зачем это делать? Тут вся проблема еще и в том, что этот код работал еще вчера, а сегодня утром - не работает. Наверное перебродил за ночь и протух

Comment: Нужен [mcve], чтобы было видно что и когда вызывается.

Comment: @Grundy попробую. Но вс] же может у вас будет мнение почему  ng-repeat при добавлении сразу не добавляет новые данные ?

Comment: Без примера того как и когда ты обновляешь свой `arr` вряд ли можно угадать. Как вариант, его обновление происходит без запуска digest цикла, поэтому ангуляр просто не знает, что надо перерисовать view. Чтобы точно сказать нужен рабочий пример, чтобы можно было запустить и увидеть - действительно не работает. Либо хотя бы цельный код, который воспроизводит ошибку. Предоставленные куски, как выяснилось, сами по себе не могут вызвать указанную ошибку.